A sentence such that the use of the contraction "y'all" would fix the ambiguity of the sentence's meaning
I'd be pleased to find out about more sentences with this property.
Here's a sentence I found which I have an inkling might be an example of such a sentence:
"I will give you all A's"
Is the teacher/professor speaking to one student or multiple students?

Even if the sentence containing "y'all" is unambiguous, "y'all" is not necessary to fix any ambiguity; the meaning can be expressed unambiguously in a different way. I'm not sure exactly what the OP wants.

Disambiguating without the usual contextual aids:  << [I will give] [every one of you] [an A]  vs <<  [I will give] [every one of you] [one or more A's] >> vs [I will give]  [you, my dear pupil] [nothing but A's]. Using 'y'all' is non-standard, and better avoided in writing and, certainly in the UK, speech.

I would like to offer a frame challenge here, I don't see that substituting "y'all" for "you all" does disambiguate whether the teacher is speaking to one or multiple students. Surely a teacher who contracts "you all" to "y'all" in front of a group of students would be just as likely to use the same contraction if a single student asked for their individual results.

@MarkBooth I live in Texas and have never witnessed someone use "y'all" when speaking to only one person. Can you point to such an example?

While y'all is on the face of it just an abbreviation of you all, it is so strongly associated with the dialects of the American South, that anybody who hears will inevitably perceive the speaker as using or imitating such a dialect. On should thus use such a formulation only if that's what one intends.

Ya'll be kind to each other.

@RosieF It's not the only way to disambiguate. All I wanted to know is whether or not it does disambiguate. Does that make my intention more clear?

The contracted, and very informal, American English expression “y'all” is indeed plural, just as “you all” is. Both have the same meaning: “every one of you”.
Compare: Have you passed? (the subject could be singular or plural) and Have you all passed? (the subject is plural).
The OP's example is marginally ambiguous, (see comments below) the teacher could be telling the individual student that they will be awarded two or more As for their assignments but this situation is highly unlikely. To avoid any possible misinterpretation, we can use the expression I mentioned earlier "every one of you"

I will give every one of you [straight] A's"


I will give you, [student's name], all A's


Although it could be addressed to one or all, you can resolve any ambiguity by looking at the teacher. Are they speaking to a single student, or to the entire class at large? If you can't tell the difference, you'll have a hard time in any classroom where teachers provide both individual feedback and group instruction.

OP is asking about the inherent ambiguity and fixes addressed other than by context.

@EdwinAshworth  Where's the ambiguity in "you all"? The OP is arguing that "y'all" resolves the ambiguity, it means the same thing, doesn't it? I would like to improve the answer but I don't see how I can. Could you please explain, in slightly more detail, why this answer has been downvoted? Thanks.

@EdwinAshworth  Ninety-nine times out of a hundred, to be sure, you-all indicates a plural, implicit if not explicit, and thus means, when addressed to a single person, 'you and your folks' or the like, but the hundredth time it is impossible to discover any such extension of meaning.

The ambiguity @Mari-LouA is whether the sentence is referring to "you all" (multiple students) with one A each, or "you" (single student) with "all A's" (multiple A's). Without further context it isn't possible to tell.

@MarkBooth Oh! I didn't see that. Still, how  likely is a teacher going to tell a student (single) that they are going to be awarded all As when assignments are usually handed individually, one at a time? If it was common practice to grade papers for an individual student three or four assignments at a time, as if they were batches, then I would agree. I don't know any professor  who marks in this way. It's a fanciful interpretation that is possible but highly unlikely.

Less unlikely than you might think, especially in earlier years learning. The question is a hypothetical, however. I can't actually image a situation where this phrase would be uttered without the context necessary to disambiguate it, but that would be a frame challenge.

The question is not aimed at the actual teacher-class situation in the example, where context will almost certainly disambiguate; it's aimed at the intrinsic 'I will give you all the money I promised you' ambiguity. I've removed the DV after 'not ambiguous' was removed.

@Mari-LouA, while it would, of course, in real life be better to remove the ambiguity by reformulating the sentence in the ways you suggested, the OP is wondering whether y'all (with the rest of the sentence remaining the same) couldn't also be way of disambiguating it, because it makes it obvious that all is to be interpreted as attached to you and not to As.

@Mari-LouA incidentally, I think your use of the word "everyone" might be inapproriate. I'll just quote a quick google search: Tip If you're unsure whether to use "everyone" or "every one", try replacing the word “every” with “each.” If the sentence still makes sense, "every one" is the correct phrase to use

We use every one, written as two words, to refer back to a noun we have already mentioned: I received more than a hundred letters from him while I was away and I’ve kept every one.

@Mari-LouA yes that's exactly what I'm saying, and that's why your use of "everyone" is inappropriate. You said the following: The contracted, and very informal, American English expression “y'all” is indeed plural, just as “you all” is. Both have the same meaning: “everyone of you”.

@SimonM dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/everyone The definition of everyone is "every person“. You can say 1 “I will give each one of you As” and  also 2 "I will give everyone [straight] As” without the "of you".

@Mari-LouA yes yes, you're using it correctly now and that's fine. My only contention is with the fact that you said "everyone of you", which makes no sense, since it should be "every one of you"

@SimonM Thanks, you're right. I'll fix it tomorrow :)

Well first I'd say the sentence is not ambiguous and might even be redundant. If the professor is speaking to the class, then he is speaking to a singular noun, like a team or a flock. So the word "you" would suffice without the use of "all" because it is understood that he is speaking to ever member of the group. If I'm a boss and I have a meeting with my employees and I say "You need to be here on time", it's the same as saying "You all need to be here on time"

As OP takes care to express this sentence, it is unclear whether the professor is addressing one, or more, students. That is the point of the question. Yes, context would almost certainly disambiguate, but there  is an inherent ambiguity ... [every one of you] [A's] (and this itself remains ambiguous) vs [you, my dear pupil] [nothing but A's].
